# Use wildcard certificate in Azure Api Managment

Tags: dns, certificate, azure-api-management

We would like to create the following setup on a **Standard** tier API Managment instance.
We have a wildcard certificate **.company.eu*, and we would like to expose 2 API's

- todo.company.eu
- weather.company.eu

We've create 2 CNAME recods pointing to the API Managment instance.
When adding the weather API all worked well - we added it without an API URL suffix

[image]

but when adding the todo API we noticed the API URL suffix field is used to identify the API on API Management,and we need to provide an API URL suffix.

[image]

Is there anyway we can work with subdomain url's without a rewrite rule in front of API management? Maybe a known workarround?

Answer (score 1):

That is not possible at the moment. APIs cannot be pinned to specific hostname, so their URL paths must be unique.

Comment: I can confirm this answer. I contacted Azure Support to double-check. You could add a policy to route to different backends based on the hostname on **one** API but there is no way to create a routing on top of **multiple** APIs.

Also as you noted already the paths across all APIs need to be unique.